# Trying to understand how TTYs and PTYs work in CentOS 6.5?

Tags: linux, tty, pty

I started to dig into the whole Linux `pty` and `tty` hell. I'm trying to understand how it works here in Linux so I was reading quite a lot of articles that covered this topic.

So far I know:

> TTYs are TERMINALS which are the last "secretary" to talk to kernel. 
>   PTS are virtual terminals, that on the one end are connected to the TTY and on the other end are connected to the terminal-emulator (the one that we can for example open by clicking applications->system tools->terminal. or to ssh session(?). So ssh uses another pts.

That seems pretty clear to me because when I will do `w` in a shell on my system I get:

```
21:26:53 up 2 days, 11:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.08, 0.08
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
kris     tty1     :0               Thu09    2days 52:28   0.05s pam: gdm-passwo
kris     pts/0    :0.0             21:18    0.00s  0.02s  0.01s w
```

The `tty1` is a terminal session, which was started when I logged into my machine, and the `pts/0` is a virtual terminal (instance of *App* -> *System Tools* -> *Terminal*).

However, what is the `pty` then? If I will connect to my server through `ssh` then another `pts` will be spawned, but when will another `tty` be spawned, and whats the point of `pty`, from the `man pty` it seems to me like it is this:

1. Emulated terminal (gui terminal) talks to `pts`
2. This `pts` in turn talks to `pty` , which talks to `tty`

That doesn't make sense.

Please try to explain it using examples because it is very easy to fall off with all the differences between consoles, terminals, virtual terminals, emulated terminals, `pts`, `pty`, `tty`.

Comment: Also this one: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)